# Docs for Bootstrap adding data-bs-overflow to body?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

I'm using Bootstrap 5 and trying to find anywhere in the documentation where it mentions how things like modals or offcanvases will add attribute `data-bs-overflow` to the body element, and not finding info.

Anyone know how this attribute is added and behaves? It's causing a weird, irreproducible situation in my code. I think it's just interacting with something else that's managing `body: overflow` but without knowing how Bootstrap's native behavior works I can't be sure

Comment: You might do better to ask about your actual problem than a suspected remedy. I don't see that attribute being added when a modal is open on my site.

Comment: The docs won't list all the classes and other attributes dynamically managed by the library. You'd have to scour the code.

Comment: If your situation is "irreproducible", how do you attribute it to this? Seems like it would be quite reproducible.